# Upgrade to windows 10 causing AWS RDS SQL Server connection error in aspnet MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, windows-10, amazon-rds

I have upgraded my windows operating system from 8.1version to 10. Earlier I am able to connect AWS RDS (SQL server) database from my asp.net MVC application but not connecting after upgrading my windows operating system from 8.1 to 10 version.

Everything is working fine on EC2 server environment and my application is also successfully connecting to the AWS RDS (SQL server).  But I am getting error like “Login failed for user ‘xxx’ when I ran database migrations using package manager console in my local system.

What would be the reason? Why I am getting this error? Before upgrade everything is worked but after upgrade to windows 10 I am getting the above problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason, It is working fine if i include port number with comma (,) at server endpoint.
like this,

```
<add name="MyContext" connectionString="Data Source=myAWSEndPointHere,1433;Initial Catalog=MYDB;User Id=MyUser;Password=MyPassword;" providerName="system.data.sqlclient" />
```